# How to show Windows' "DLL not found" error in my program in C++?

Tags: c++, dll, error-handling, throw

I have searched what I am looking for in this website; but I don't understand.

So, I have written this question.

I wrote a .dll file and a program in C++ (Code Blocks IDE). If dll file and program are in same directory, my program will work.

But if I delete dll file and execute my program, Windows shows me this error:

"xxx.exe has stopped working."

I want to "The program can't start because xxx.dll is missing from your computer." message instead of this.

What should I do?

Comment: You probably need to specify that .dll as dependency in your [application manifest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374191(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Why would you want this? A normal user has no permission to alter files in  `\Program Files\YourApp\` and an Administrator should be trusted not to break programs. And if they still do, they should understand the consequences of their action.

Comment: @MSalters Users will do all sorts of things, including "deleting all those unnecessary files". That' stupid, sure, but that doesn't mean it won't happen. And why do you assume that it is about systems with a competent administrator?

Comment: @Aziuth: Because Windows won't even let non-administrators into `C:\Program Files\ ` anymore! It's hidden _and_ protected. They don't even have listing permissions on the directory, let alone delete permissions.As for idiots with the administrator password, they can break your system in so many ways that you cannot effectively deal with even a fraction of them. To name just a few idiot ideas: renaming `\Program Files\ ` or subdirectories therein, changing access permissions, random registry changes. Don't make their actions your problem, that's hopeless.

Answer (score 1):

There are three kinds of linking you can do.

- **Load-Time linking** is when a DLL is loaded automatically when your program starts up. Windows finds this DLL usually in the same folder as the executable.
- **Run-Time linking** is when you specifically load a DLL by calling LoadLibrary in your code.

> When the application calls the LoadLibrary or LoadLibraryEx functions, the system attempts to locate the DLL (for details, see Dynamic-Link Library Search Order). If the search succeeds, the system maps the DLL module into the virtual address space of the process and increments the reference count. If the call to LoadLibrary or LoadLibraryEx specifies a DLL whose code is already mapped into the virtual address space of the calling process, the function simply returns a handle to the DLL and increments the DLL reference count. ~ [taken from here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685090%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

What you want to do is a run-time link to your dll and test the result instead of what you are currently doing.

- > Visual Studio offers a third option, delay-loaded DLL's.~ MSalters

which handles the loadLibrary calls for you.

Comment: Visual Studio offers a third option, delay-loaded DLL's. Not an option for CodeBlocks/MinGW though.

Comment: Thank you for the information! As a MinGW user I was unaware this feature existed. Will edit the answer to contemplate your comment.